# What are the pros/cons of using Spring Boot with embedded server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What are the pros/cons to using Boot with embedded server rather than conventionally deploying war to web server?

I realize it is a great fit for development and also seems to be embedded in most discussions surrounding microservices.  Is this model intended to be deployed to production?  Seems like tuning the embedded server could be problematic not to mention heap requirements.

Comment: you can do most of the tuning you could do with a standalone server. I use Tomcat 8 with several microservices to run a 40000 user application and this is running better than our websphere servers ... I never missed one of the parameters Tomcat supports in its server.xml

Answer (score 1):

**Pros:**

- You can create the entire applications in a fast track manner. Not
  very in depth knowledge of Spring framework is required. It defaults
  a lot of settings or in other words convention over configuration.
- Good for developing micro services in docker environment. Spring
  Cloud Netflix OSS is one such example.
- It has embedded tomcat servlet container and you write code as if you
  are writing a standalone Java code with plain old main method. This
  way you are focusing more on the developing the business logic
  rather than plumbing aspects.

**Cons:**

- As it's rapid application development with convention over
  configuration and you really want to control each and every aspect of
  the application - then you need to know everything that is happening
  under the hood. For any further code changes you just don't have to
  go thru the source code but each and every configuration that is done
  by Spring boot for you.
- Lots of JAR files and settings are created for you so it might impact
  the overall footprint of the app as well as impact the performance.
  Yes you can work on it but you need to know what's going on under the
  hood.
- I don't think that the convention over configuration does the best
  configuration for the embedded server. You should be looking into
  each and every configuration settings of embedded server to optimize
  the run time performance of your application.

Answer (score -2):

The most important to my opinion is auto configurations and parent starters which solve a lot of confifurations..

You can start writing business logic instead of handling installations.

Embedded is just to make it easier for you, all configuration is done by spring boot and you can override it.

In addition you can create traditional war and deploy as you need but there is a lot of facilities behind spring boot that it is really fabulous.

Take a look on [this presentation](https://prezi.com/jdvcty1zgmd_/spring-boot/) which explain the main things

Comment: I personally like this presentation: http://de.slideshare.net/mobile/ewolff/java-application-servers-are-dead

Comment: This isn't an answer but actually the question he asked. He wants to know the pros/cons of the embedded container. Not the pros/cons of Spring Boot.

Comment: What i was written about is spring boot with embedded container. If you are in to writing web application than spring boot with embedded container goes together, If you are trying to write some other service then you don't need embedded container and you can use bunch of other stuff